# VBA Macro to drill down into dimension member

Tags: excel, vba, essbase

I am trying to create a macro to simulate drilling down into a dimension member (Time), this is off of an excel plugin to assist with finance stuff.

Currently, when you Highlight the Time Dimension (A12) and click `Zoom In` it will display all years from 2020 - 2050. If I highlight Cells A13-A15 (2020,2021,2022) and click zoom in, it *should* display the Children attached to those years (Q1,Q2,Q3,etc.) and if you click `Zoom In`  further it *should* display leaf level data as months.

What happens instead of displaying all the values you requested based on the highlighted selection (Children or leaves) it will only take the top cell value and apply that 'Zoom In' feature to the top cell highlighted.

I.e. I highlight 2020 - 2023, and click `Zoom In` it will only zoom in on the top value 2020 and ignore the other values highlighted. I am trying to create a macro to work around this but coming up short. I have no experience with macros so I am trying to figure this out as I go.

So far, I have

```
sub sd()
Range("A13 ").Select 
End Sub
```

This will expand to show the Quarters for 2020, but if I highlight Q1-Q4 and click `Zoom In`  it will only apply to Q1.

I am stuck, any assistance or direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SmartView aka Essbase?

Comment: Your VBA procedure appears to do nothing.  Did you leave out some code? Whatever add-in you're using may have an API for running certain calls via VBA.

Comment: @BigBen Yes looking for that exact same functionality! What function(s) would you recommend?

Comment: There's a VBA API: https://docs.oracle.com/applications/smartview/620/SVDEV/toc.htm